# Android: New line character from mysql does not work in textview

Tags: android, mysql, newline

I am saving some text in mysql db (longtext type) which contains new line character something like:

```
Hello World
This is a test
Thanks
```

I am sending value in db via php like this:

```
$message = 'Hello World' . "\n";
$message .= 'This is a test' . "\n";
$message .= 'Thanks;
```

I can see that new line character is saved in db and it shows fine.

However in TextView I see all text joined, there is no new line character. This is how TextView shows it:

```
Hello WorldThis is a testThanks
```

What I have tried:

- Setting `android:singleLine="false"`
- `msg.replaceAll("\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"))`

FYI, if i type same message containing new line in android application itself then TextView shows newline characters correctly but it is just not getting new line character coming from mysql db :(

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
msg.replaceAll("\n","<br />");
```

then on the text view use

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(msg));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace \n with "html br tag" and

use this method `yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));`

Comment: I want to display it in android TextView not php application

Comment: but there is no setHTML method on TextView